# Javascript - Sort by date?

Tags: node.js, sorting, datetime

I'm trying to sort by date in JS. They are in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. How can I sort this chronologically? Will I need to splice it up and measure difference in time for each piece or something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is how do you sort an array by DateTime in javascript.
Nothing to do with the node environment your JS is running on.

```
  var array = [{id: 1, date: Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM}, {id: 2, date: Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM}];

  array.sort(function(a,b){
     // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
     // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
     return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

** while we are on the subject on using node, you can also simply use underscore and sort it with little effort.

```
  _.sortBy(array, function(o) { return new Date(o.date); })
```

Comment: it is worth mentioning that the anonymous function defined here in the `array.sort` argument, will sort the entries by date from newest to oldest, while `_.sortBy` will sort them from oldest to newest. I'd suggest using lodash instead of underscore, since it provides both _.sortBy and _.orderBy (which allows to control the order of your sorting)